# Branch.io: Extract custom value from link

Tags: web, sdk, branch.io

we're facing a problem right now: We're using the SMS gateway feature from branch.io which simply does not work properly worldwide (e.g. Lituanian cell phones won't receive any messages at all).

Therefore i need a fallback method for people that cannot receive an SMS to their phone with the downloadlink in the Appstore. (The branch.io Links have an effect on the branding of our app)

The fallback is to let them use a voucher code which COULD be generated from a custom value that we store for each Link

[This is an ordinary Link with its 2 custom values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRsYp.png)

The landing page http://learnmat.ch/spark7 opens in the browser and i'd like to be able to identify the SponsorID on the website so that i can return a voucher code that is suitable for the specific SponsorID of the Link.

Right now i've already integrated the Web SDK into the website.

Is that "reverse engineering of the SponsorID" possible based on the Link and the WebSDK integration?

I'd really appreciate your help!

Thank you,
Sven

Answer (score 1):

Jackie from Branch here.

Our SMS page service supports international numbers but only if the number the SMS has to be delivered is in the same country the SMS is being sent from. Could you please make sure the sender is physically located in Lithuania? I'd also suggest creating your own Twilio integration if you want to bypass these restrictions we have on our system https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/text-me-the-app/#use-your-own-sms-service

Regarding your fallback method: you want to have users click on a Branch link that will open your website and based on the link data (sponsor ID), you want to provide them with unique voucher codes? If my assumption is correct, you can achieve this by custom event tracking and user identity tracking. (relevant docs: https://docs.branch.io/pages/dashboard/analytics/#user-value-attribution)

Hopefully, this helps. Let us know if you have additional questions about the info above, or about anything else related to integrating Branch.

Best,

Jackie Choi